# 18.04 - No Internet Connection - Realtek RTL8111

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet, realtek

I just tried installing Ubuntu on a new Desktop I got from a friend of mine, and I am unable to connect to the internet.

I am an extreme noob with Linux, so please take it easy on me.

I managed to figure out that the Network card is a Realtek RTL8111, and after some googling, it seems to be that this card has some problems with Ubuntu. Every solution I found either required an internet connection to fix, or was for a much older version of Ubuntu, where I couldn't really follow the steps, as they weren't working for me.

I've tried following some solutions, but my lack of skill with Linux didn't help me much.

I do have a working Windows laptop, where I could download any necessary files, if that would be needed.

I tried download a driver from here: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2
and then moved it to the Linux computer via USB Drive, I then unzipped the file (which in it self needed some googling on my part, that's how big of a noob I am) but then when I tried installing it, I was getting a message requiring some packages, such as "make" or something of that sort.

I would really appreciate your help guys! And please, I would appreciate detailed step by step instructions, as otherwise I would probably get lost, and as I said, I do have a working laptop where I could download any necessary files.

PS: I am trying to connect via Cable, and that's not working. I don't think that card has Wifi...

Thank you very much!

Rudy

Edit: Motherboard is Gigabyte GA990FXA-UD3

Comment: can you try to boot from 18.04 usb again, connect via LAN cable and this time try "try install ubuntu" and see if its working. Also try connecting wifi from the live session.

Comment: When you click the Network Manager icon at the upper right, do you see an available wired or ethernet connection? What happens when you click it? Are there any clues in the log? From the terminal: `dmesg | grep -e r816 -e enp` The driver file you downloaded is for kernel versions up to 4.7. You have the much newer 4.15. It is useless and may safely be deleted. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome! 

it does show me that there is a wired connection, but then after a minute or so, I get a pop up saying "Connection Failed, Activation of Network Failed". 

After running that command in the terminal, I got something like

"Can't disable ASPM, OS doesn't have ASPM Control."

As well as:

"Link is not ready"

"Link Down"

Comment: could u please run the wifi-info-script and append its resault to your question https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/669014

Comment: Hi Alex, I might have explained this wrong... the computer doesn't have Wifi... only LAN.

Comment: This sounds very much like a dodgy ethernet cable. Have you confirmed that the cable is good? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a` Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

The steps I took to solve this isse were:

- I had to disable the r8189
- I needed to install the r8168 from mtorromeo https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168
- Execute: `ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg on`
- I needed to add the above into my startup scripts by creating:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh -e
  ethtool -s ens133 speed 100 duplex full autoneg on
  exit 0
  ```
- adding it to `rc.local`